# Strip the ending of a specific string off end of a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

The string I have is "Last Updated on November 7, 8:00 PM AST".
Using regex I want to remove "AST" off of the end of it. How do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 5):

Using regex, you could do this:

```
var string = "Last Updated on November 7, 8:00 PM AST";
var modified = string.replace(/ \w{3}$/, '');
```

Though, if it is always going to be the last three characters (and the space) in the string, this will probably be faster:

```
var modified = string.substring(0, string.length - 4);
```

Answer (score 4):

No need regex, just get the substring up till the last index of a space character.

```
var s = "Last Updated on November 7, 8:00 PM AST";
s.substr(0, s.lastIndexOf(" ")) // "Last Updated on November 7, 8:00 PM"
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove "AST" specifically with regex, you would do this:

```
var lastupdated="Last Updated on November 7, 8:00 PM AST";
var changed = lastupdated.replace(/AST$/,"");
```

To also remove the space preceding "AST" with regex, do this:

```
var lastupdated="Last Updated on November 7, 8:00 PM AST";
var changed = lastupdated.replace(/ AST$/,"");
```

However, if you want a more general solution, this will remove the final 4 characters of the string, assuming they are 3 letters preceded by a space:

```
var lastupdated="Last Updated on November 7, 8:00 PM AST";
var changed = lastupdated.replace(/ \w{3}$/,"");
```

---

But, as others have noted, you do not really need regex to do this, and thus could simply use any of these general methods:

```
var lastupdated="Last Updated on November 7, 8:00 PM AST";
lastupdated.slice(0, -4); \\trims final 4 characters off of the end of the string
lastupdated.substr(0, s.lastIndexOf(" ")); \\prints the string up until the final space character
lastupdated.substring(0, string.length-4); \\prints all but the final 4 characters of the string
```

All of these methods result in the string `"Last Updated on November 7, 8:00 PM"`

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not need to use a regex:

```
var s = "Last Updated on November 7, 8:00 PM AST".slice(0, -4);
```

However with a regex:

```
var s = "Last Updated on November 7, 8:00 PM AST".replace(/.{4}$/, '');
```

If you are sure that `AST` can only be at the end due to the restritive format, you can also do the replace like:

```
yourString.replace(' AST', '');
```